# Python- Installed requests module, added it to the path, but still not registering when I run a program and import it

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I installed and use the requests module on my machine, and it works fine, but I need it to work on a remote desktop I connect to.

When I `pip install requests` or `pip-2.7 install requests`, or `easy_install requests`, it tells me the requests module is installed. When I open up IDLE and use it in a program, it tells me that there is not a module called requests. I have tried moving around the requests folder, or duplicating it, as well as adding the path to my PATH. Other than reinstalling Python, I am at a loss right now. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What's the value of `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Some of these are redundant but for the moment, I prefer to cover all bases. C:\Program Files\ImageMagick;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\shared\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\RAC5;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\SysMgt\oma\bin;D:\ProcessMonitor;C:\Python27\SydneysArc\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\Python27\SydneysArc\Scripts;C:\Python27\SydneysArc\Tools\Scripts;C:\Python27\SydneysArc\python;C:\Python27\SydneysArc\Lib\site-packages\requests;C:\Python27\SydneysArc

Comment: Hmm, OK. So requests is definitely on there. Do you have multiple python versions installed?
(Note: It may be faster and easier to just reinstall python. I know that's not what you want to do, but it'll probably fix the problem.)

Comment: Only one version, off to re install now. Thanks!